# How to post invitation on friend's wall after Facebook breaking change on Feb 6 2013?

Tags: php, facebook

Firstly, I actually spent a lot of time to search for the answer but I still cannot find a proper solution, so I decided to post a question here, hopefully some one can provide me at least ... some hints.

My problem is:

According to [Facebook road map](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013),  There's a change in "Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API ", this affects an inviter project which I'm currently working on for my company. Now, I cannot post invitation on friend's wall, this will make our app completely useless.

I tried to figure out 2 solutions as below:

- Using Facebook Graph API to post a feed on my wall and tag the friend that I want to invite on that feed. This solution works fine but it will post thousand of feeds on wall and it is not good.
- Using Facebook Chat XMPP I sill cannot manage to make it work. But by using this, there's a high change that our application can be banned by Facebook because of spamming.

My question is: Besides 2 solutions above, is there any better way to post invitation on friend's wall?

If there's no other solution, can anyone tell me how to post a feed that is hidden from timeline using GraphAPI? (For timeline not be polluted by invitation feed)

Comment: i have the same problem, i tried with share dialog but no success, any help please?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-the-friends-wall

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I cannot post invitation on friend's wall, this will make our app completely useless.

Maybe you were not supposed to “spam” walls for the purpose of inviting people in the first place … and that loophole is being closed now.

*Requests/Invites* are the mechanism you’re supposed to be using for stuff like this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: as I understand about Request, it is used to invite friends to my **canvas** application on Facebook.But, our application's purpose is to allow any user on a website to invite their friends on Facebook to join that site. This application will be deployed into many websites. So each site has to create an Canvas Application, and this application will navigate user to the expected website, it is awkward. Also, request seems to require to be sent manually.